# How to interact with a JSON configuration file in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

My frontend depends of a json configuration file that holds various parameters that can modify the content of the page.

When the test starts, my file has a specific content.
I would like to find a way to write this file but only for the current test so no state is left for the next test.

This is my current solution, but problem is that if tests fail, the original version of the file is not reset. What could be another approach ?

```
it('should work a specific way with the given configuration', () => {
    cy.readFile('my-app/parameters.json').then(
      (originalFile) => {
        // Modify the json file however I'd like
        cy.writeFile('my-app/parameters.json', someConfiguration);

        // Test details
      
        cy.writeFile('my-app/parameters.json', originalFile);
      }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing really wrong with what you're doing (it's like resetting a database).

But perhaps use a different name for the original?

```js
it('should work a specific way with the given configuration', () => {
    cy.readFile('defaultParameters.json').then(
      (originalFile) => {
        // Modify the json file however I'd like
        cy.writeFile('parameters.json', someConfiguration);

        // Test details
      }
    );
  });
```

Keep in mind when the test fails mid way you might not write the original back.

Move `cy.readFile('defaultParameters.json')` to `cy.fixture('defaultParameters.json')` since Cypress caches the fixture read.

See [fixture - Loaded just once](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Loaded-just-once)

> Please keep in mind that fixture files are assumed to be unchanged during the test, and thus the Test Runner loads them just once. Even if you overwrite the fixture file itself, the already loaded fixture data remains the same.
>
> If you wish to dynamically change the contents of a file during your tests, consider cy.readFile() instead.

Comment: I took the name `parameters.json` for simplicity's sake but the file is located in my app code, not inside the `cypress` folder. There is only one file that can be modified for the changes to apply. I'm not sure to understand what to do with the `originalFile` in your answer. By the way, I indeed forgot about the case where the tests fail and the original cannot be rewritten, I have no clue how to address this problem so far.

Comment: A cleaner option would have been to mock my Vuex store data since this data is stored inside the store for my app but I'm not sure it's possible

Comment: **what to do with the originalFile** ... the same as you do in your question example ... **Modify the json file** ...

Comment: **There is only one file that can be modified** - there's nothing to stop you having a copy in the `cypress/fixtures` folder.

Comment: **the file is located in my app code** sounds like messing with that file from with the test might be a bad idea. Some for of stubbing (of app reading parameters.json) is in order, but question lacks the details. The Vuex store data is in-memory not a file, so not sure of the connection.